# Joomla | Breadcrums links to a category which doesn't respect the global blog layout

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm using BT-Content-Slider to display news in the front page of my site. The articles which that module catches belong to a category named "Category1". When i access to an specific article loaded on that module, breadcrumbs are displayed this way:

```
Home > Category1 > Article
```

The link of Category1 is:

```
http://www.joomlawebsite.com/index.php/cat_id-Category1
```

where `cat_id` is the category identification number.

The problem is that the category layout doesn't take the global configuration layout that is set in the joomla backend and uses another configuration that i don't know where to change.

That's all, i hope i made myself clear. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The front-end was showing a menu item assigned to almost every module in the page.